# how to search for string in file

Tags: java, string, file

How could I search for string in text file in java?
Would it have to be in a text file or could it read a .ini or some other file type
example

```
sound = off
opengl = on
openal = off
```

I tried searching for it on google but I couldnt really find anything.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can process any file as if it contains text (.ini files happen to actually contain text). Possible duplicate of [Finding line number of a word in a text file using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548519/finding-line-number-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of information with those typical of questions.

Here you have two easy examples:

- Loading Java Properties Files http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/10/loading-java-properties-files.html
- How do I load property settings with the Properties class? http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=581608

In short it is easy to load a file into a `Properties` object, for example to obtain, in your case, the `sound` value in a `example.properties` file:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("example.properties"));
String isOnOrOff = props.getProperty("sound");
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to use a [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file.

You can load one using `Properties.load(String path);`

Answer (score 2):

If your file is a `properties` file or an `ini` file (`key = value`), you may want to use the [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html) API. It is much better than the `Properties` class from the JDK.