# How to replace an string after a specific line in a file using java

Tags: java

I have a situation similar where I need to change a line in a batch file if similar string not found.

Suppose I have a code like below in batch(I know it is not correct code as it a dummy only)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 if (user == '1234') {
   ENV DEV
   set DB myDBDEV
   set Excel myExecelDEV
   set API MyAPIURLDEV
 } elseif (user == '5678') {
   ENV UAT
   set DB myDBUAT
   set Excel myExecelUAT
   set API MyAPIURLUAT
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want java to read above file, find ENV as DEV and change the value like myDBDEV, myExecelDEV, MyAPIURLDEV etc.

I am able to find the line number by using below code

```
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\batch\\MYbatch-env.csh");
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
        String data;
        String result = new String();
        int i=0;
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            if(data.contains("ENV DEV")) {
                System.out.println("line number -> "+i);
            }
            result = result.concat(data + "\n");
        }
```

I have tried below code but that was not return line number so I use above approach

[Finding line number of a word in a text file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548519/finding-line-number-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I also tried below approach but it seems not working

[How to replace an string after a specific line in a file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809375/how-to-replace-an-string-after-a-specific-line-in-a-file-using-java)

Now problem statement is replaceAll function will remove all key but I want to remove the next string of key means value. and it is a text as string not a hashmap kind thing,

In if block if DB string is myDBDEV2 then I want to change the values to myDBDEV

Example:

If below string found

```
   ENV DEV
```

Then below value should check value of key DB and replace if not found required value

```
   set DB myDBDEV
   set Excel myExecelDEV
   set API MyAPIURLDEV
```

And main thing is code should make change in if block only, else if variables should be affected as an file example I have shown in above URL.

Comment: Seems like you just want to do something like `result = result.replace("ENV", "DEV");` for example if you wanted to change all `ENV` places to `DEV`. Then use the code in [this question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file/20040289) to write `result` back to the file. Try to actually read the code and see what it's doing (read the comments) and this is a very similar task. The three things you are doing is 1. reading the file, 2. replacing text in the file, 3. writing the file back with the replaced text.

Comment: Yes did it and already posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution work for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filepath= "C:\\Users\\Demo\\Desktop\\batch\\Demo.sh";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
        String data;
        String result = new String();
        int lineNumber=0;
        int i=0;

    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        i++;
        if(data.contains("My String data")) {
            System.out.println("line number -> "+i);
            lineNumber=i;
            break;
        }
        result = result.concat(data + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    lineNumber=lineNumber+1;
    System.out.println(lineNumber);
    String Mystring ="    Mystring";
    String Mystringline = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filepath)).get(lineNumber-1); // get method count from 0 so -1
    System.out.println("Line data ->> "+Mystringline);
    if(!Mystringline.equalsIgnoreCase(Mystring)) {
         setVariable(lineNumber, Mystring, filepath);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Mystring is already pointing to correct DB");
    }
    System.out.println("Succesfully Change");
}

public static void setVariable(int lineNumber, String data, String filepath) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    lines.set(lineNumber - 1, data);
    Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
}
```